# how to post like and comment on a youtube video programmatically with video ID ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, youtube-data-api

I've authenticated with OAuth2, how can I comment and post likes to a video id's?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Youtube data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)-

For comments: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments

For likes: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate

Please note that there are daily/monthly cap on API usage. You can check all the quotas in your Google API console. Don't forget to have a look at this [quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, how can I get the total number of likes of the video?

Comment: Use this api for likes/dislikes: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating